# BigQuery: Is there a transfer fee when exporting a BigQuery table from US Multi Region to GCS in another region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a transfer fee when exporting a BigQuery table from US Multi Region to GCS in another region?

As shown below, only US multi-regions can be exported to other regions.
However, there is no mention of the cost of the operation.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data?hl=en

> Exception: If your dataset is in the US multi-regional location, you can export data into a Cloud Storage bucket in any regional or multi-regional location.

It is stated in various places that copying a dataset or copying a GCS between regions incurs a transfer fee.
However, there is no mention of the transfer cost for this export operation.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide: Data Warehousing, Analytics, and Machine Learning at Scale](https://books.google.com/books/about/Google_BigQuery_the_Definitive_Guide.html) book,
 there will be a network charges for transferring data between regions when using export ([see](https://books.google.com/books?id=-Jq4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=bigquery+export+from+us+multi-region+to+another+region+charges&source=bl&ots=QgwbX267YM&sig=ACfU3U0z3S1LS0R8f3p9iCqlXIDl7ivv9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8hsvLn4rpAhXWGTQIHdgpBlYQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=bigquery%20export%20from%20us%20multi-region%20to%20another%20region%20charges&f=false) **Data locality** section).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information.
In the end, we designed the system so that it does not export across regions.